# The glass-half-full/glass-half-empty distinction beyond Fregean semantics?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, semantics, frege

What's a useful framework within which to make sense of the glass-half-full/glass-half-empty distinction? In particular, one which admits both descriptions as not only valid but also useful, that is, carrying content which cannot be reduced to one or the other.

The only thing I can think of is the Fregean sense/reference distinction, from the point of which these assertions are co-referential since they describe the same state of affairs (or because they both describe a *true* sense of affairs), but differ in their sense, since one draws attention to a presence and the other to an absence.

I would be grateful for any pointers to a more recent treatment of the subject.

Comment: I suppose you can also interpret them in terms of Austin's speech act theory as having the same literal (locutionary) meaning but different [perlocutionary force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlocutionary_act).

Comment: @Conifold The problem with that is speech acts have to be uttered. A person may think a glass is half-full or half-empty without making an utterance. Understanding it as a conversational implicature has the same drawback. It seems to be more a question of propositional attitudes. I am disappointed that this glass is half-empty, vs. I am pleased that this glass is half-full.

Comment: This is really about pragmatics more than semantics, so you would probably do better to ask the question on a linguistics forum.

Comment: Think metaphor:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor